# How to make my slackbot reply in a thread, instead of to entire channel using Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, slack-api

I try to get a slackbot to provide tech-support by replying to certain key-words in messages.
However, its responses clutter the channel it is in.
Therefore, I want my Slackbot to reply in a thread under the original message, as I would do when answering the question myself.

From the Slack documentation, I know it should be possible to reply to a message in a thread. I should somehow use `thread_ts` but I can't get it to work.

```
var POST_MESSAGE_ENDPOINT = 'https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage';
var TEXTS = [
  'Hi there! Maybe I can help you?',
];

  //Reply to  within a thread: 
  //data '{"channel":"CHANNEL-ID", "text":"curl", "thread_ts":"THREAD-TS"}'

function doPost(e){
  var event = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents).event;

  if(event.hasOwnProperty('bot_id')){
    return;
  }else if(event.text.match(/(log.?in)|(inlog)|(logging?)/)){
    postLogin(event, ['login']);
  }else if(event.text.match(/(syncing)|(sync)|(sync$$)/)){
    postSyncing(event, ['syncing']);
  }else if(event.text.match(/(issues?)|(problem)/)){
    postIssueOptions(event, ['issue']);
  }
}

function postLogin(event, keywords){
  var url1 = "<https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rcaGjyAMFpo9tG9YAgTpTFlxPZq5luwBlM3gMVCL9eI/edit|Runner can not login after changing password>";
  var url2 = "<https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rcaGjyAMFpo9tG9YAgTpTFlxPZq5luwBlM3gMVCL9eI/edit|Runner forgot password>";
  var url3 = "<https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rcaGjyAMFpo9tG9YAgTpTFlxPZq5luwBlM3gMVCL9eI/edit|Other login issue>";
  var random_params = Math.floor(Math.random() * TEXTS.length);
  var payload = {token:SLACK_ACCESS_TOKEN, channel:event.channel, text:TEXTS[random_params] + '\n' + url1+'\n'+url2+'\n'+url3};
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(POST_MESSAGE_ENDPOINT, {method: 'post', payload:payload});
}

function postSyncing(event, keywords){
  var url1 = "<https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rcaGjyAMFpo9tG9YAgTpTFlxPZq5luwBlM3gMVCL9eI/edit|Syncing does not work>";
  var url2 = "<https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rcaGjyAMFpo9tG9YAgTpTFlxPZq5luwBlM3gMVCL9eI/edit|Yesterday's trips are still showing>";
  var random_params = Math.floor(Math.random() * TEXTS.length);
  var payload = {token:SLACK_ACCESS_TOKEN, channel:event.channel, text:TEXTS[random_params] + '\n' + url1+'\n'+url2};
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(POST_MESSAGE_ENDPOINT, {method: 'post', payload:payload});
}

function postIssueOptions(event, keywords){
  var url1 = "<https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rcaGjyAMFpo9tG9YAgTpTFlxPZq5luwBlM3gMVCL9eI/edit|Delivery missing in trip>";
  var url2 = "<https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rcaGjyAMFpo9tG9YAgTpTFlxPZq5luwBlM3gMVCL9eI/edit|Runner App directs Runner back to hub>";
  var url3 = "<https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rcaGjyAMFpo9tG9YAgTpTFlxPZq5luwBlM3gMVCL9eI/edit|Trip assignment does not work>";
  var random_params = Math.floor(Math.random() * TEXTS.length);
  var payload = {token:SLACK_ACCESS_TOKEN, channel:event.channel, text:TEXTS[random_params] + '\n' + url1+'\n'+url2+'\n'+url3};
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(POST_MESSAGE_ENDPOINT, {method: 'post', payload:payload});
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Here is a slightly outdated, but still relevant overview of how threading works: https://api.slack.com/docs/message-threading

Comment: Hi Erik, thanks for your quick reply.
I checked the documentation and also some of your other answers on this site. However, I am basically clueless as to how to make it work in my specific piece of code. Can you maybe provide me with some pointers? 
Where do I get the `thread_ts` and where do I include it in my response?

Comment: Post a new message which has the `thread_ts` parameter set to the `ts` value of the message you want to reply to.

Comment: Managed to fix it, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To open a new thread to an existing message all you need to do is post new message which has the `thread_ts` parameter set to the `ts` value of the message you want to reply to.

The whole concept of threading is also nicely explained in this slightly outdated, but still relevant [overview of how threading works](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-threading).

Comment: @willem evers if this answer solved your issue please consider marking it as solution by clicking on the checkmark. TY!